# SMPS input impedance as function of frequency

Tags: filter, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm designing SMPSs with buck, boost and flyback topologies. I'm primarly using classical L-filter as the input filter.

It is important to make the output impedance of the input filter considerably lower than the input impedance of the SMPS because the SMPS's input impedance acts like a negative resistance that could otherwise lead to instability.

I was reading an application note made by TI ([snva538](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva538/snva538.pdf)) when I came across this picture.
[image: Impedance as function of frequency]

What puzzles me is the shape of the input impedance of the SMPS as function of frequency.

I have used to just calculate the worst case impedance as a function of input voltage (the lowest input voltage) and use that value to decide if the output impedance of the input filter is satisfactory. Now the picture above indicates that this would not be enough and I should also calculate the worst case point and its value as function of frequency too.

So my question is what are the parameters and phenomenons affecting the input impedance of a SMPS as a function of frequency and how to mathematically deal with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is what are the parameters and phenomenons affecting
>   the input impedance of a SMPS as a function of frequency and how to
>   mathematically deal with them?

This has made me think a little (a dangerous thing!). An SMPS of the type in the TI document is basically a DC-to-DC converter and not an AC-to-DC converter. I wanted to make that clear so there is no misunderstanding of what I'm talking about in my answer.

By input impedance, we have to "consider" applying a small sinewave on top of the DC input voltage and then analysing things. That small sinewave will be "modulated" by the switching action inside the converter and you'll get a signal (before the LC output filter of the switcher) that looks something like this: -

[image]

Clearly this is only the AC part of the output waveform; it will of course be superimposed on a DC voltage. Now, if you perfectly low pass filtered the AC waveform you would obtain a sinewave of exactly the same frequency as the inputted sinewave but smaller in amplitude.

The reduction in amplitude is because of the switching converter's duty cycle but, this is of no consequence because the real point is that a switching converter will still output a frequency that corresponds with the sinewave superimposed on the input voltage.

OK so far?

So, what happens when this "modified" sinewave meets the LC filter on the output of the converter. I call it an LC filter because that is exactly what it is: -

[image]

Yes, the L and the C form a fundamental part in transferring energy from the switched waveform to the steadier DC output but it's still an LC filter.

That LC low pass filter will be fairly high Q. In other words, it is capable of being very resonant because the DC losses in the inductor are, by design, intentionally small and additionally, it is well understood that the LC natural resonant frequency **MUST** be significantly lower than the lowest switching frequency. If the switching frequency were largely coincident with the resonant frequency then you have a major problem because the LC will act as a series resonant network directly from switching node to 0V and this will devastate functionality.

So, if the small sinewave transferred (by switching action) to the input of the LC has a frequency coincident with the natural resonant frequency of that LC then you theoretically have a switcher with zero input impedance.

This is why an SMPS of the type in the document (e.g. any buck regulator) will naturally have an input impedance that drops to quite a low value at some particular frequency and, this frequency is determined fundamentally by the output filter resonant frequency.

Added to this is the input decoupling capacitor across the input wires of any switching converter. In other words there is a general falling of input impedance as frequency rises. Given also that the switching transistor won't have zero ohms on resistance there is a slight lessening of the resonant effect described above.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn’t noticed the formula in the design example in the appendix of the application note so I wasn’t even sure if the phenomenon was due to the low pass elements in the output side of the SMPS. Now if we consider the propagation path it makes the thing even worse for buck and flyback converters since the AC propagates better in the worst case situation where input voltage is low and duty cycle is longest. However for boost converters this is lucky since their duty cycle reduces with input voltage so it will attenuate this “parasitic” effect on input impedance in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is of an open loop input impedance. The Mathcad used in the document shows "D" is fixed. However, it needs to be stable with the closed loop input impedance which wont have that dip. See figure 14 of SNVA801 which compares open and closed loop.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Your answer is pretty short and could be improved; consider better citing and linking the document you have in mind, and embedding the relevant figure, to better make your point.